# Test for RVs with known probabilities?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, random-variable, random-generation, uniform-distribution

I have written code that generates a sequence of distinct integers. The integers are assumed to occur in the sequence with fixed probabilities.

For example, if the sequence contains the numbers [-1,0,25,99] with respective probabilities of [m,n,q,p], how can I test the generated sequences, to test that the generated sequences contain the integers in the correct numbers (given the known probabilities)?

In other words, is there a p-value or other metric I can use as a cutoff or threshold, to determine whether the generated sequences have the correct statistical properties (i.e. they contain the expected integers in the correct ratios)?

Comment: Your title doesn't seem to match the body of your question. A uniform distribution across four possible values would be one where m=n=p=q. Please clarify your title

Comment: @Glen_b: My bad, changed title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to test the hypothesis of several categorical responses would be the [G test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-test) or [multinomial test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_test) (when testing a set of multinomial proportions, these are demonstrably the same test, in spite of Wikipedia's article on the G-test [plainly suggesting they're different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-test#Distribution_and_usage)). The test statistic is

$G = 2\sum_{i} {O_{i} \cdot \ln\left(\frac{O_i}{E_i}\right)} .$

Probably the most common approach would be to use the chi-squared test of goodness of fit:

$\chi^2 = \sum_{i} {\frac{\left(O_i - E_i\right)^2}{E_i}} .$

In both cases, $O_i$ is the observed count in category $i$ and $E_i=Np_i$ is the expected count ($N$ is the total count of observations across all categories and $p_i$ is the expected proportion $(m,n,q,p)$.

In each case, for 4 groups the statistic is usually compared with a chi-square distribution with 4-1=3 degrees of freedom, which approximation works well if the expected counts are not too small.

There are other tests, though they may be less well known.